# if statement is skipped even the statement is true

Tags: python

I just began on the TCP server and client programming on python. however one of the of the if statement does not work and it does not make any sense:

```
while (1):
    data = s.recv(1024)
    if data == 'finish':
         break
    print data
print 'Finish'
```

and sometimes the last lane will print 'finish' in stead of 'Finish' and it cant exit the loop. This should be never happened because the 'print data' statement is skipped if data='finish'. Could someone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: save yourself the headache and just do `data.lower()` if you you are getting different casings of 'finish'.

Comment: since I am using c.send('finish') on the server side so data will not be 'Finish'.

Comment: Try `print repr(data)` instead to see exactly what you're receiving. There might be a hidden character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because you sent the bytes in one call to `send` does not mean that you will receive them in one call to `recv`. They might arrive in smaller or larger groups. E.g. perhaps you send:

```
c.send('one')
c.send('two')
c.send('three')
c.send('finish')
```

But you receive

```
s.recv(1024) -> 'onetwothreefinish'
```

Or maybe you receive

```
s.receive(1024) -> 'one'
s.receive(1024) -> 'two'
s.receive(1024) -> 'three'
s.receive(1024) -> 'fin'
s.receive(1024) -> 'ish'
```

Comment: If that were the problem it should have been obvious, because `print` will put a newline between each chunk received. You make a good point though.

Comment: It's pretty hard to say that without knowing exactly what's being sent. If the last message before the 'finish' was just whitespace or a newline it could be very hard to notice the difference.

Comment: so is there any way to avoid this ?

Answer (score 1):

you can just compare with `data.lower` to ensure that all uppercase letters are changed to lowercase letters, also change the while loop and remove the redundant braces

```
while True:
    data = s.recv(1024)
    if not data:
         break
    print data
print 'Finish
```

Comment: well I dont think that is the case since on the server side i am using c.send('finish') so the data will not be 'Finish"

Comment: i don't think this is the proper way to check if the data is done sending i've always checked that by using `if not`...i've edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

The comparison is case sensitive. Use data.lower() in the if statement